# Min-max theorem

Tags: analysis, polynomials, optimization

If $f$ is a polynomial. Prove that there is a $y\in \mathbb{R}$ which $|f(y)|\le |f(x)|,$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$:

I said since $f$ is a polynomial it's continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ so we can use the theorem of $a=\min, \max=b$ value, so $f(x_a)\le f(y)\le f(x_b)$ assuming that $f(x_a) = -f(x_b)= -f(x)$ then we got $-f(x)\le f(y)\le f(x)  \le   |f(y)|\le f(x)\le |f(x)|$, proved

Is this correct?

Comment: \mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{R}$ and \leq to get $\leq$.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Can you give a precise statement of the theorem you're trying to use?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem ,it's this theorem where u say if $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$ then it takes a minimum and maximum value $m<=f(x)<=M$

Comment: OK, but this theorem says that $m\le f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, not for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So I think you need to think a bit harder about how this helps for your problem. One comment that might help is that if you assume that $f$ is continuous, but not necessarily a polynomial, then the conclusion does not hold (for example, $f(x)=e^{x}$). So at least one part of the argument will have to use a special property of polynomials that isn't true of every continuous function.

Comment: well ye but assuming it's a polynomial I thought I could take  a subset of $R$ $f$ which I forgot to write, for example $[c,d]$ where this can happen, I dont think it's entirely wrong or dunno

Comment: Yes, this will lead to a proof. But how will you choose $[c,d]$? And what happens to $f(x)$ for $x$ not in $[c,d]$? [These two questions are related.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Since $|f(x)|\geq0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, clearly if it has a root, then we can take this for $y$ and $|f(y)|=0\leq|f(x)|$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Otherwise, as Harald Hanche-Olsen points out, $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}|f(x)|=\infty.$$ Since a polynomial has at most $n-1$ turning points, we can find $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $|f(x)|$ has no turning points for $x<a$ and $x>b$. This means the minimum of $|f(x)|$ is contained in $[a,b]$ (otherwise it will have a turning point, which is a contradiction). Now we can apply the Extreme Value Theorem to conclude $|f|$ has a minimum, i.e., there exists a $y\in[a,b]\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $|f(y)|\leq|f(x)|$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work a bit harder. If $f$ is a constant polynomial, you can pick any $y$. So assume $f$ is not a constant. Then $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$. So, fix any $c\in\mathbb{R}$. By the limit statement before, you can find $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $|f(x)|>|f(c)|$ whenever $x<a$ or $x>b$. Now, can you see how to go the rest of the way?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ has a root. Then this root is your minimum.

Suppose now $f$ has no root, and wlog we assume $f>0$. [1]. Then $f$ has a derivative which must (reason to the degree) have a root. [2] But one of it's roots is therefore a global minimum. This states the claim.

Edit: [1]: This means the leading coefficient of the polynomial has to be positive.
[2]: Also, the leading coefficient has to be non-negative, which states that at least one of the roots leads to a minimum.

Comment: Btw, min-max-theorem is for compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, it will not work here.

Comment: Why do you assume $f$ has at most one root?

Comment: He didn't. But anyhow, a rational function such as $(1+x^2)/(1+x^42$ is a counterexample to the notion that any positive function with at least one critical point has a minimum. (Not only that, the above function has a local minimum at $x=0$.)

Comment: "Then $this$ root is your minimum". Isn't there an assumption that there is one root and one root only?

Comment: @GitGud I think there must have been an edit to the question, where you see an earlier version than I see. Edits made quickly don't show up in the edit history. And the quote you gave does not appear in the answer as I see it.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I opened the question on another computer and I see the same answer  from which I got the quote.

Comment: uhh I am a little bit confused here, have been studying analysis for like 1 week :p

Comment: @GitGud: Oh, in the first paragraph. But that is obviously true, so I wasn't even looking at the first paragraph. No, “this” does not imply uniqueness in that context. *Any* root of $f$ will be a minimum of $|f|$ after all.

Comment: @poffer: Disregard the answer above. It is wrong, and my first comment on it is meant to show why, since if the given proof were correct, it would also show that $(1+x^2)/(1+x^4)$ has a minimum, which it does not. (You could use the simpler function $1/(1+x^2)$ to the same end.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen So sorry, I missed that triviality.

Comment: If a real polynomial has no root, it must have an even degree. So it's derivative has an odd degree, and therefore has a real root. @Harald: Your function is no polynomial. It's a real serie. So it is no counterexample.

Comment: Your proof, as written, does not use any property [1] of polynomials not shared by my example. Therefore, my example shows that your proof is wrong. It is of course not a counterexample to the result originally asked about, since that is true after all. [1] Well, it uses *one* property of polynomials, but that is used only to show the existence of a critical point, and my function has one anyhow.

Comment: I see your point. It is a property of a polynomial, that is all positive, to have a minimum, since it's leading coefficient has to be positive, and therefore the leading coefficient of the derivative has to be non-negative, too, and so it has a minimum. So this was the property missing in my proof.